# Want to Eval sublimerepl in different group, but to append to existing opened tab

Tags: python, sublimerepl

I managed to edit my sublimerepl user config (from a previous post) by appending the following:

```
{ "keys": ["f8"], "command": "repl_open", 
             "caption": "Python",
             "mnemonic": "p",
             "args": {
                "type": "subprocess",
                "encoding": "UTF-8",
                "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
                "cwd": "$file_path",
                "cmd_postfix": "\n", 
                "env": {},
                "suppress_echo": true,
                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                "external_id": "python"
                } 
}
```

This evaluates my code in a new group (as configured in my Sublimerepl config "open_repl_in_group": true). It also does so in a new tab in that new group. If i evaluate the code the second time, it opens a new tab.

Is there a way to evaluate the code and produce the output by appending to the existing tab which was opened earlier?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After starting a you need to use `Tools | SublimeREPL | Eval in REPL | File` or `Ctrl+, f` keyboard shortcut.